# Android SQLite: CursorIndex out of Bounds

Tags: android, sqlite

Hello I'm getting an OutOfBoundsExpection: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0. My database was working before.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
MainActivity.db = new DatabaseHandler(ncontext);
MainActivity.db.addPokemon(new Pokedex(0, "Bulbasaur", "001", "Grass/Poison", "Lv 5",1));

//Crashes:
Log.d(tag,"This is drawable: "+ MainActivity.db.getPokemon(0,1).getPokemonImage());

//DataBase class

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_POKEMON, columns, KEY_ID + "=?" + " AND "
                + KEY_POKEMON_IMAGE + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id),
                String.valueOf(poke_image) }, null, null, null, null);
        if ((cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) ){
            cursor.moveToNext();
            cursor.close();
        }
        Log.d(Tag, "pre pokedex fetch");
        Pokedex pokemon;

        //CRASHES
        Log.d("Database","1: " + Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        // return pokemon
        pokemon = new Pokedex(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3),
                cursor.getString(4), Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(5)));
        Log.d(Tag, "getPokemon done");
        return pokemon;
```

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: why you are closing `Cursor` `if ((cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) ){
            cursor.moveToNext();
            cursor.close();
        }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing cursor and moving cursor to next position without processing with first result set within `if` condition. correct your `if` condition like below

```
 if ((cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) ){

        Log.d(Tag, "pre pokedex fetch");
        Pokedex pokemon;

        //CRASHES
        Log.d("Database","1: " + Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        // return pokemon
        pokemon = new Pokedex(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3),
                cursor.getString(4), Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(5)));
        Log.d(Tag, "getPokemon done");
        return pokemon;
        cursor.close();
 }
```